# How do I control a non-browser window that is part of Firefox?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, applescript

I'm on OSX using Python 2.x, Selenium & Firefox

I'm automating testing a javascript webapp with Python & Selenium.

One of the links (Add File) in the application opens up a non-browser firefox window titled "File Upload" which looks like (/is?) a Finder window.

Is there a way that I could locate and control this window from my python script?  I know Selenium can't do it, but I wondering if it might be possible with something like 'import applescript' and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [atomac](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/atomac/1.1.0) which allows me to control mac apps through their accessibility controls (which needed to be enabled on Mavericks for Aptana in System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Accessibility).  Cool tool, but the documentation is pretty sparse.  The examples provided on the page above got me to the point where I could close the window via the cancel button, but I had to review the function definitions in atomac's AXClasses.py to figure out the rest.  Here's the solution.

```
import atomac, time
from atomac.AXKeyCodeConstants import *

# to allow me to make firefox frontmost while testing
time.sleep(5)

# get a reference to the running app
firefox = atomac.getAppRefByLocalizedName('Firefox')

# get the window of the reference
firefoxwindow = firefox.windowsR()[0]

# send key sequence to go to my home folder
firefoxwindow.sendKeyWithModifiers('h',[COMMAND,SHIFT])

# send key sequence to select first file there
firefoxwindow.sendKeyWithModifiers('a',[COMMAND])

# press the now active Open button
openbutton = firefoxwindow.buttons('Open')[0]
openbutton.Press()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's theoretically possible, but *really* awkward. I'll give you a bunch of links--not ideal, I know, but you could write a book on this.

You'd need to start by [enabling AppleScript control of the GUI](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5914). Then you'll want to read up on [how to control the GUI](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/) from within Applescript. However, you wanted to use Python and not AppleScript, so then you'll need to install [PyObjC](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/index.html), which is a Python to Cocoa bridge. You'd need to use the Scripting Bridge framework and figure out (from the [extremely thin documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/apinotes/ScriptingBridge.html)) how to translate the AppleScript docs to Python.

Comment: Thanks!  Looking through this stuff and at things related to the scripting bridge, I found atomac and with it the solution.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.